# How to use np.put when target array is more than 2d?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to change BGR image elements. 
In detail, if 2nd element equals 3rd one, both of them are changed to 0.

```
arg1 = np.argwhere(img[:, :, 1] == img[:, :, 2])
np.put(img[:, :, 1], arg1, 0)
np.put(img[:, :, 2], arg1, 0)
```

I tried this but doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does work but just not the way you might be expecting. `np.put` expects the indices of multi-dimensional matrices as tuples, while `np.argwhere` gives you a 2d-array of rows and columns.

To make it mush simpler, you can use boolean masks and get the job done-

```py
mask = img[:, : ,1] == img[:,:,2]
img[:, :, 0][mask] = 0
```